# I want to get all matches with regex. Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, match, combinations

I am sorry for my english.

```
var r=/([a-z]*)[a]{1}([a-z]*)/igm;
var s="araba";
```

The result I need,

```
a raba index:0
ar a ba index:2
arab a index:4
```

How can I do that with regexp ?

Comment: You want this just for the character `a`? Or this could be applied with other characters?

Comment: Yes I will enclose it in brackets for all statement. For example,s="şelaleler". r=/([a-z]+)[l][1}[e]{1}([a-z]+)/; result= şela le ler, şelale le r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single regular expression call will not be possible as regular expressions can't go back after they match something. You'll have to make a regex that will look for the character set you want (in your example `[a]`) and stop at every match, generating a new result and pushing it into an array (or use it directly). `RegExp.prototype.exec` is needed like this:

```js
function mySplit(str, charList) {
    // regex will match any character provided in the charList string (no need for {1} as it is the default)
    var regex = new RegExp("[" + charList + "]", "g");
    // the result array, will contain object indecating where the match was found and the parts
    var result = [];
    
    // before starting, execute the regex on the string str
    regex.exec(str);
    // using do-while to guarantee that there will be at least one result in the result array
    do {
        // the index of this match
        var index = regex.lastIndex - 1;
        
        // the result object for this match
        var r = {
            index: index,              // the index
            parts: []                  // the parts (for example "a", "raba" ...)
        };
        
        var p;
        // PREFIX PART
        p = str.substr(0, index);      // get the prefix
        if(p.length) r.parts.push(p);  // if not empty push it
        // THE CHARACTER
        p = str.substr(index, 1);      // get it
        if(p.length) r.parts.push(p);  // if not empty push it (this is could be empty if nothing is matched)
        // POSTFIX PART
        p = str.substr(index + 1);     // get it
        if(p.length) r.parts.push(p);  // push it if not empty
        
        result.push(r);                // push the object r as a result
    } while(regex.exec(str));
    
    return result;
}

console.log(mySplit("araba", "a"));
```

**Note:** the second parametter to `mySplit` could as much letters as you want. For example `mySplit("araba", "ab");` will return this:

```
[
    {
        "index": 0,
        "parts": [
            "a",
            "raba"
        ]
    },
    {
        "index": 2,
        "parts": [
            "ar",
            "a",
            "ba"
        ]
    },
    {
        "index": 3,
        "parts": [
            "ara",
            "b",
            "a"
        ]
    },
    {
        "index": 4,
        "parts": [
            "arab",
            "a"
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you İbrahim :)
My extended solution :

```js
String.prototype.matchAllCombinations=function(regex,includeIndex,constGroups){
 var str=this;
 var includeIndex=includeIndex||false;
 var constGroups=constGroups||[];
 var newRegex;
 if(constGroups.length==0){
  var groups=regex.source.split(new RegExp('([(]{1}[^()]+[)]{1})','g'));
  var newSource='';
  for(var el,it=1,lim=groups.length-1;it<lim;it++){
   el=groups[it];
   if(el.charAt(0)!='('){
    newSource+='('+el+')';
    constGroups.push(it-1);
   }else{
    newSource+=el;
   }
  }
  newRegex=new RegExp(newSource,'');
 }else{
  newRegex=regex;
 }
 var testStr=str;
 var combinations=new Array();
 var matches=new Array();
 var combination=new Array();
 var end=new String();
 var k=new Number();
 var constValues=new Array();
 var itCount=new Number();
 var lastTestStr=new String();
 while((matches=testStr.match(newRegex))!=null){
  k=2;
  correct=true;
  combination=new Array();
  combination=matches.slice(1,matches.length);
  if(combination[combination.length-1]!=""){
   k=1;
  }
  combination[combination.length-k]+=end;
  end=combination[combination.length-k];
  if(itCount==0){
   for(var it=0;it<constGroups.length;it++){
    constValues.push(combination[constGroups[it]]);
   }
  }
  testStr=combination.slice(0,combination.length-k).join('');
  if(lastTestStr==testStr){
   combinations=[];
   break;
  }
  for(var it=0;it<constGroups.length;it++){
   correct&=(combination[constGroups[it]].length==constValues[it].length);
  }
  if(correct){
   if(includeIndex){
    combination["indexes"]=new Array();
    for(var it=0;it<constGroups.length;it++){
     combination["indexes"].push(combination.slice(0,constGroups[it]).join('').length);
    }
   }
   combinations.push(combination);
  }
  lastTestStr=testStr;
  itCount++;
 }
 return combinations;
}
console.log('araba'.matchAllCombinations(new RegExp('([a-z]*)[a]{1}([a-z]*)'),true));
console.log('araba'.matchAllCombinations(new RegExp('([a-z]*)[a]{1}([a-z]*)[a]{1}([a-z]*)'),true));
console.log('araba'.matchAllCombinations(new RegExp('([a-z]*)[a]{1}([a-z]*)[a]{1}([a-z]*)[a]{1}([a-z]*)'),true));
console.log('araba'.matchAllCombinations(new RegExp('([a-z]*)[a]{1}([a-z]*)[a]{1}([a-z]*)[a]{1}([a-z]*)[a]{1}([a-z]*)'),true));
console.log('araba'.matchAllCombinations(new RegExp('([a-z]*)[p]{1}([a-z]*)'),true));
console.log('erebe'.matchAllCombinations(new RegExp('([a-z]*)([a]{1}|[e]{1})([a-z]*)'),true,[1]));
```